# Spec-ing a class that instantiate something

Tags: php, bdd, phpspec, prophecy

Let's say I have this class that I was spec-ing (following BDD approach)

```
class Logger
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function logMessageAsRead(Message $message)
    {
        $log = new LoggedMessage($message);
        $this->em->persist($message);
    }
}
```

and `LoggedMessage` is defined as follows

```
class LoggedMessage
{
    private $date;

    private $message;

    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
        $this->message = $message;
    }
}
```

Sometimes my spec example fails due to discrepancy from `Message` date instantiated in spec and the one in the `Logger` class.

```
class LoggerSpec
{
    public function it_logs_a_message(Message $message, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $log = new LoggedMessage($message);
        $em->persist($log)->shouldBeCalled(1);

        $this->logMessageAsRead($message);
    }
}
```

Question number one: Do I have a smell in my code, so do I need to create a collaborator (ie.: a factory) and inject it into `Logger` in order to create a new `LoggedMessage`?

Question number two: If is not necessary to inject a new collaborator, how can I be sure that my spec works every single time and not fail in a random fashion due to date time discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

1. An injected factory of `LoggedMessage`s would be a good solution, especially if you don't want to close the constructor of `LoggedMessage` against modifications. In general, it's good to separate the concern of creating an object from using it.
2. The simplest solution would be to check for a specific type instead of a concrete instance:

   $em->persist(Argument::type(LoggedMessage::class))->shouldBeCalled(1);

If you want your expectation to be more specific, you can use `Argument::which` or `Argument::that`:

```
$em->persist(Argument::which('getMessage', $message))->shouldBeCalled(1);
$em->persist(Argument::that(function($arg) {
    return $arg->getDate() instanceof \DateTime;
}))->shouldBeCalled(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All your consideration are same as mine so I guess that a factory is the only way to do this. However second point is not a good one: it's too little tighter for this kind of example (phpspec example to be clear)